# error when passing id in bootstrap modal

Tags: php, codeigniter, bootstrap-modal

i am new in codeigniter

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $row) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $i++;?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $row->orderid;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->order_date;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->name;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->price;?></td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-<?= $row->customerid?>">View Details</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal-<?= $row->customerid?>" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Order Details</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p><strong>Product Name</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $row->name;?></p>
          <p><strong>Quantity</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $row->quantity;?></p>
          <p><strong>Price</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $row->price;?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

only details of the first row is displayed in all modals 
i need to get the details of each from each modal

Comment: show the query you have written to get the data

Comment: public function list_orders() {            
   $this->data['rows'] = $this->order_model->get_orders(); 
   $this->load->view('list_orders', $this->data); 
 }

Comment: this is my controller function

Comment: show the function get_orders()

Comment: public function get_orders(){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('orders o');
$this->db->join('order_detail od', 'od.orderid = o.serial','left');
$this->db->join('tbl_products p', 'p.prod_id = od.productid','left');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
 }
}

Comment: Please use `echo "<pre>"; print_r($rows); echo "</pre>";` and provide this result in comment box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can help you with bootbox modal plugin(http://bootboxjs.com/). Modify your html as follows

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <!-- dialog body -->
          <div class="modal-body">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <div></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

then delete your button code and replace with this code

```
<a  class="btn btn-primary  your_defined_class_name_for_jquery_use" data-id="<?php echo $row['whatever_id']?>" > What ever name</a>
```

add the below script on the bottom of the page

```
<script>$(className).on('click','your_defined_class_name_for_jquery_use', function (e) {
    var id=$(this).data('id');
    var dialog = bootbox.dialog({         
        title: title,
        message: $('<div></div>').load(url_to_your_controller_which_shows_the_data ),

    });

});
```

Make sure that jquery is previously loaded on the page. I think this will help you.

Comment: thank u somehow i got the ans i had  mistake in id  also

Answer (score 0):

Try to bellow code:

```
function get_orders(){ 
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('orders o');
    $this->db->join('order_detail od', 'o.serial = od.orderid', 'left');
    $this->db->join('tbl_products p', 'p.prod_id = od.productid', 'left');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

use this line `$this->db->join('order_detail od', 'o.serial = od.orderid', 'left');` 
not `$this->db->join('order_detail od', 'od.orderid = o.serial','left');`